# Need to decide how many goals a team scores (soccer simulator) in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a text-based soccer simulation. I'm finding it difficult to write the method that decides the number of goals a team scores. Each team has attack and defense levels (at the moment it's out of 20). My program *is* functional, but I'm looking at ways to make it more realistic, including a chance of surprises (lately they happen a lot in the league IRL). Here is the method I wrote:

```
public static int determineGoals(Team t1, Team t2)
    // Determines how many goals a team scores by comparing attack and defense levels
    {
            double percent = randDouble(1, 100);
            int goals = 0;

            if (t1.attack - t2.defence >= 15)
            {
                    if (percent <= 5)
                    {
                            goals = 0;
                    }
                    else if (percent <= 25)
                    {
                            goals = rand(1, 2);
                    }
                    else if (percent <= 90)
                    {
                            goals = rand(3, 4);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            goals = rand(5, 6);
                    }
            }

            else if (t1.attack - t2.defence >= 7)
            {
                    if (percent <= 10)
                    {
                            goals = 0;
                    }
                    else if (percent <= 30)
                    {
                            goals = rand(1, 2);
                    }
                    else if (percent <= 92)
                    {
                            goals = rand(3, 4);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            goals = rand(5, 6);
                    }
            }

            else if (t1.attack - t2.defence >= 3)
            {
                    if (percent <= 20)
                    {
                            goals = 0;
                    }
                    else if (percent <= 55)
                    {
                            goals = rand(1, 2);
                    }
                    else if (percent <= 94)
                    {
                            goals = rand(3, 4);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            goals = rand(5, 6);
                    }
            }

            else if (t1.attack - t2.defence >= 0)
            {
                    if (percent <= 25)
                    {
                            goals = 0;
                    }
                    else if (percent <= 70)
                    {
                            goals = rand(1, 2);
                    }
                    else if (percent <= 96)
                    {
                            goals = rand(3, 4);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            goals = rand(5, 6);
                    }
            }

            else if (t1.attack - t2.defence >= -3)
            {
                    if (percent <= 30)
                    {
                            goals = 0;
                    }
                    else if (percent <= 75)
                    {
                            goals = rand(1, 2);
                    }
                    else if (percent <= 98)
                    {
                            goals = rand(3, 4);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            goals = rand(5, 6);
                    }
            }

            else if (t1.attack - t2.defence >= -7)
            {
                    if (percent <= 35)
                    {
                            goals = 0;
                    }
                    else if (percent <= 85)
                    {
                            goals = rand(1, 2);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            goals = rand(3, 4);
                    }
            }

            else if (t1.attack - t2.defence >= -15)
            {
                    if (percent <= 65)
                    {
                            goals = 0;
                    }
                    else if (percent <= 95)
                    {
                            goals = rand(1, 2);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            goals = rand(3, 4);
                    }
            }

            else
            {
                    if (percent <= 75)
                    {
                            goals = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            goals = rand(1, 2);
                    }
            }

            return goals;
    }
```

If you have any ideas I would like to hear them, including completely new algorithm ideas.

Edit: Also, I realized that I use a random double but treat it as an int (1-100), I will change that.

Comment: Your code seems to already do what you want. What is the question?

Comment: When I run the simulation, 99% of the times one of the best 2 teams win it (by a big gap as well) which I guess is realistic but I feel that smaller teams have absolutely 0 chance of beating the big ones, and the top 6 is pretty much the same every time. So I would just be happy to see ideas that would make it possible for small teams to win against bigger ones (maybe just a different percentage distribution.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a random double generator function to randomize the attack and defense scores a bit. By doing this you won't have the 'straight results' but they may bend the outcome in suprising ways a bit. You can research gaussian distribution for this to 'steer' it a little bit.

Comment: I already wanted to add transfer windows in which teams get either a boost or a decrease in value slightly (by failing or succeeding in bringing good players, probably in a range of -2 to 2) but in my opinion, these scores should be pretty much static at the first season as these are real teams and I want the simulation's first season to end somewhat close to real life.

Comment: Then you have to incorporate a dataset that you can gather of real life competitions and use machine learning to predict some outcomes that you can incorporate into your outcomes. But that can be quite the learningcurve.